# If I push the pointer of an element allocated on the stack into an std::vector its member's values get altered

Tags: c++, visual-c++, vector, stack

If I add more than 2 items to the `std::vector<A*>` in the way shown below, the member's values of the added items change
Here is a `Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

struct B;

struct C
{
    float x;

    C(float x)
    {
        this->x = x;
    }
};

struct A : public C
{
    bool begin;
    bool visible;
    B* b;

    A(float x, B* parent)
       : C(x)
    {
        begin = false;
        visible = false;
        b = parent;
    }
};

struct B
{
    A a1;
    A a2;

    B(float x1, float x2)
         : a1(x1, this), a2(x2, this)
    {
        a1.visible = true;
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<B> bs;
    std::vector<A*> as;
    bs.push_back(B(1, 2));
    as.push_back(&bs.back().a1);
    as.push_back(&bs.back().a2);
    bs.push_back(B(2, 3));
    as.push_back(&bs.back().a1);
    as.push_back(&bs.back().a2);

    for(auto& it : as)
    {
        std::cout << it->begin << std::endl;
    }

    std::cin.get();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

There's another Problem with the above code(it already got mentioned in the comments by tobi303):
The pointer `B* b` from struct `A` becomes invalid due to `push_back(B(...))` copying the instance of `B`, the solution is to use `emplace_back` instead

Comment: Can you please provide the exact piece of code and example output with mysterious two segments?

As a side note, your ctors have some fields initialized in init-lists while others are assigned in the bodies.

Comment: not sure if this is related to the problem, but I noticed that your `Endpoint` holds a pointer to the `Segment`, however, when you place the segment into a `vector` a copy is made which invalidates those pointers (they are still pointing to the temporary that you push). `emplace_back` might solve that issue

Comment: There isn't much else to it, I was just testing around, but sure I can add all the code(I thought ist better to shorten it). Do you want to tell me it is a Problem if I mix iniatializer lists and initializing in the Body?

Comment: `endpoints.push_back(segments.back().p2);` will not compile.

Comment: sorry thats my bad should be a '&' before segments

Comment: I also tried unsing `emplace_back` by simply replacing `push_back` and it gave the same result(it didnt work either)

Comment: @sro5h That `&` gives you a pointer that becomes invalid as soon as `push_back` returns.

Comment: So how is the right way to do it?

Comment: What happens when your vector is resized? What does the copy constructor/destructor of your classes do? Without that information how can we explain the weird behavior here?

Comment: Ill add the full code of the structs if thats gonna help. Btw I dont define a custom copy constructor nor a destructor.

Comment: Ok give me a Minute ill create a Minimal, Complpete and Verifiable example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that when more elements are added to a vector it may resize itself. When this happens all elements are moved to a new location and all existing pointers and references to elements get invalidated.

There are containers that do not invalidate iterators when new elements are added, such as `std::list` and [`boost::stable_vector`](http://bannalia.blogspot.co.uk/2008/09/introducing-stablevector.html).

I.e. `boost::stable_vector<Segment>` or `std::list<Segment>` instead of `std::stable<Segment>` would fix the issue, provided you do not require contiguous storage of `Segment` elements.